# 9 patch not working

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have created 2 9 patch images, from them 1 is working perfect and 1 is not working. Tried to create it more than 10 times but everything failed. Don't know the reason and that is why in need of some help from community.

[image: This is working perfect]

[image: Not working]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/imgPhoto"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgPhoto"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessageDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yesterday 4:25 PM"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessageSnippet"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtMessageDate"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="How are you?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

// This is not workin - the light blue one

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlContentOwner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/imgPhotoOwner"
        android:layout_below="@id/rlContent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgPhotoOwner"
        android:background="@drawable/new_right_side_bubble"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessageDateOwner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yesterday 4:37 PM"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessageOwner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtMessageDateOwner"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="I am fine"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need such big 9 patches, since they will be stretched. Make sure their extension is **.9.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need such big 9 patches, since they will be stretched.
I redesigned them both like this:

`speech_left.9.png` [image] and `speech_rite.9.png` [image]

This is the result I got (I'm only showing the azure one):

[image]